# How do bonuses such as "+20% production" affect factories?

Tags: tropico-4, tropico-3

When upgrading buildings or customizing El Presidente, you are offered a couple of options that affect production by a certain percentage, for example `+20% Production`. You know that you will somehow get more output from your buildings but the actual effect/mechanic is not perfectly clear.

Suppose I have 100 units of raw material that convert to 100 units of finished goods in one cycle. Does a `+20% Production` bonus mean that

1. I will receive 120 units of finished products out of 100 units of raw material (better input/output ratio)
2. I will receive 120 units of finished products but consume 120 units of raw material (same input/output ratio, faster rate).

In case you are getting more output for the same input, it's almost always a good idea to purchase factory upgrades but otherwise it's only useful if you have tons of stock or understaffed buildings.

Comment: Great question. You could play a sandbox game and manufacture something using only imports, so you have precise numbers on the materials involved. Compare that to the output from exporting the result.

Answer (score 1):

I've played through various Tropicos, including 3 and 4.

I've always understood it to be #1, but I guess I haven't explicitly tested it. Some buildings have upgrades that separately affect production and resource consumption, so from that I would extrapolate that one does not automatically affect the other.

One example would be the Sports Line upgrade for the [Car Factory in Tropico 4](http://tropico.wikia.com/wiki/Car_Factory) (emphasis added):

> Sports Line: For $12,000 and 5 megawatts of power, the factory can produce flashy, high-powered sports cars, *increasing production by 50% but increasing the amount of raw materials needed to make cars by 25%*.